# Create files in Django with user input

Tags: python, django

I am building a Django messaging app where each chat room has its own template, model and view. What I'm struggling with is figuring out a way for a user to create private chat rooms with user input. I wanted the user to specify details in a template form and when they click submit, the files will be generated to create the chat room. Or is there a better way to do this? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

oh and I am using Django 2.1.2 with Python 3.6.5. Thanks

edit: I add some code below

models.py:

```
class Chat(models.Model):
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
#timeNow = models.DateTimeField()
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
message = models.TextField()
file_upload = models.FileField()
class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "general Chat"

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.message
```

views.py:

```
def GeneralChat(request):
c = Chat.objects.all()
documents = Document.objects.all() #file upload
return render(request, "channels/generalChat.html", {'generalChat': 'active', 'chat': c, 'documents': documents})

def Post(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    msg = request.POST.get('msgbox', None)
    time = datetime.now()
    c = Chat(user=request.user, message=msg, created=time)

    c = Chat(user=request.user, message=msg)

    if msg != '':            
        c.save()
    return JsonResponse({ 'msg': msg, 'user': c.user.username})
else:
    return HttpResponse('Request must be POST.')

def Uploads(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/generalChat')
else:
    form = DocumentForm()
return render(request, 'channels/uploads.html', {
    'form': form
})
```

generalChat.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}
<div><title>General Chat</title></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="chat-body" class="panel panel-default">
    <div id="panel-heading" class="panel-heading"><h4>General Chat</h4></div>
    <div id="msg-list-div" class="panel-body">
        <ul id="msg-list" class="list-group">

            {% for obj in chat %}
                {%if obj.user == request.user %}
                    <li class="text-right list-group-item">
                    <font color="#3498DB">{{ obj.user }}</font><br><font color="#000000"></font>{{ obj.message }}
                    <br><font size="1" >{{ obj.created }}</font></li>
                    <br>
                {% else %}
                    <li class="text-left list-group-item">
                    <font color="#1ABC9C">{{ obj.user }}</font><br><font color="#000000"></font>{{ obj.message }}
                    <br><font size="1" >{{ obj.created }}</font></li></li>
                    <br>
                {%endif%}   
            {% empty %}
                <li class="text-right list-group-item">No messages yet.</li>
            {% endfor %}
            <h4>Files</h4>
            {% for obj in documents %}
                {%if obj.userUpload == request.user %}
                    <li class="text-right list-group-item">
                    <font color="#3498DB">{{ obj.userUpload }}</font><br>
                    <a href="{{ obj.document.url }}"><font color="#000000">{{ obj.document.name }}</a></font>
                    <br><small>{{ obj.created }}</small></li><br>
                {% else %}
                    <li class="text-left list-group-item">
                    <font color="#1ABC9C">{{ obj.userUpload }}</font><br>
                    <a href="{{ obj.document.url }}"><font color="#000000">{{ obj.document.name }}</a></font>
                    <br><small>{{ obj.created }}</small></li><br>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}


            <script>
                var chatlist = document.getElementById('msg-list-div');
                //chatlist.scrollTop = chatlist.scrollHeight;
            </script>
        </ul>
                <div><a class="btn btn-warning" value="Upload File" href="{% url 'uploads' %}" >Upload File</a></div>


    </div>
</div>
<div id="form-input" style="height: 100px;">

    <form id="chat-form" method="post" action="/post/">{% csrf_token %}
        <div id="chat-bottom" class="input-group">
            <input type="text" id="chat-msg" name="chat-msg" class="form-control"/>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <input class="btn btn-default" id="send" type="submit" value="Send"/>
            </span>
        </div>

    </form>

</div>

<script src="{% static 'chat.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'jquery.cookie.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

chat.js

```
$('#chat-form').on('submit', function(event){
event.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
    url : '/post/',
    type : 'POST',
    data : {msgbox: $('#chat-msg').val() },

    success : function(json){
        console.log(json);
        $('#chat-msg').val('');
        $('#msg-list').append('<li class="text-right list-group-item">' + json.msg + '</li>');
        var chatlist = document.getElementById('msg-list-div');
        //chatlist.scrollTop = chatlist.scrollHeight;
    }
});
});

function getMessages(){
if (!scrolling){
    $.get('/messages/', function(messages){
        console.log(messages);
        $('#msg-list').html(messages);
        var chatlist = document.getElementById('msg-list-div');
        //chatlist.scrollTop = chatlist.scrollHeight;
    });
}
scrolling = false;
}

var scrolling = false;
$(function(){
/*$('#msg-list-div').on('scroll', function(){
    scrolling = true;
});*/
refreshTimer = setInterval(getMessages, 5000); //0.5 seconds
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#send').attr('disabled','disabled');
$('#chat-msg').keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val() != ''){
        $('#send').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else{
        $('#send').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
});

//using JQuery
function getCookie(name){
var cookieValue = null;
if (document.cookie && document.cookie != ''){
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i=0; i < cookies.length; i++){
        var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);

        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
            break;
        }
    }
}
return cookieValue;
}

var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

function csrfSafeMethod(method){
// these http methodes don't need CSRF protection
return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
beforeSend: function(xhr, settings){
    if(!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain){
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    }
}
});
```

Comment: This seems like entirely the wrong approach. Why would you need a separate model or view for a chat room?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to make different chat rooms work with a single model or view so I created one for each chat room. I am also new to Python/Django so my understand of how these things work might be limited.

Comment: You're going to need to post some code. What is different between chat rooms?

Comment: Right now the only difference is the name of the chat rooms and the messages/files that people have posted which get stored to a database and can be viewed in the admin site. But in the future I would like to have different permissions like who can join and what are they allowed to post and more visual customization.